# Как повысить производительность фильтра ListCollectionView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Есть `ListCollectionView` у которой указан вот такой фильтр             `ListCollection.Filter = CustomerFilter;` . Проблема в том, что когда в коллекции больше 20-30 элементов то подвисает окно во время срабатывания фильтра. Как это можно оптимизировать?

```
private bool CustomerFilter(object item)
    {
        var customer = item as RecordVm;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_find) || customer != null && customer.Description.Contains(_find);
    }

public string Find
    {
        get { return _find; }
        set
        {
            if (_find != value)
            {
                _find = value;
                ListCollection.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
    private string _find;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой тип у `customer.Description`?

Comment: @VladD, Тип  `string`

Comment: Странно. Вы бы спрофилировали тогда, потому что ваш фильтр должен быть быстрый. Да, кстати: а какая длина у ваших строк?

Comment: @VladD, Средняя длина строк около 50 символов.

Comment: 30 поисков в строках около 50 символов — это мало. Попробуйте таки спрофилировать.

Comment: @VladD, Насколько я понял, профилировщик указывает что вся нагрузка идет из `set` свойства `Find`. Добавил скрин.

Comment: Окей, а внутри что? Судя по всему, виновато `ListCollection.Refresh()`. А кстати, как часто у вас вызывается сеттер `Find`? Странно, что `CustomerFilter` вообще не в списке.

Comment: @VladD, `Find` привязан к `TextBox`, срабатывает только при вводе. Впринципе достаточно ввести 1 символ чтобы форма немного подвисла. Если записи уже немного отфильтрованы, то каждый следующий фильтр срабатывает в разы быстрее.

Comment: Есть простой метод выявления тяжелых мест в алгоритме. Как только подвиснет — жмите остановку в дебаггере, в большинстве случаев попадете в самое тяжелое место в выполняемом коде. И смотрите тогда в стек. Если видите циклические вызовы или рекурсивные — вот и ваш клиент. По факту, поиск в 50 строках — фигня. Единственное искать начиная с 1 символа — это не гуд на больших массивах, но если записей до 1500 (в памяти) то будет незаметно.